# Can someone help me derive this formula for the hidden height of a distant object due to the curvature of the earth?

Tags: trigonometry

[image: 1]

Here’s my diagram and the formula I’m trying to get to.

$h_0$  = height of the observer.

$h_h$ = the hidden height.

$r$   = radius of the earth.

$d$   = distance between the two along the curved surface of the earth

If you could do this step by step I would greatly appreciate it. And I’m not sure if this is quite the right website for this so sorry if it is not.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Are you assuming the earth is spherical for simplicity

Comment: @FShrike yes. Assuming it is perfectly spherical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can show you why the formula you wrote works. I assume the formula you wrote is correct, and I will not derive it from first principles - these are just my thoughts upon seeing it:

Consider a set-up whereby the line extended out to the observer, of length $r+h_0$, is the hypotenuse of a right triangle, and the side adjacent to an angle at the centre of the Earth is of length $r$. This angle is given by $\cos^{-1}(r/(r+h_0))$, and the expression $d/r$ gives the angle at the centre of the real triangle in radians, so their difference tells you how much more the observer is bent away from the thing they are looking at. Cosine of that angle will give you $A/H$ in the right triangle formed by the radius of the earth and an hypotenuse of length $H_h+r$. Take $r/\cos$, you get the hypotenuse $r+H_h$, and then taking away $r$ gives you $H_h$. With pictures now!

If you excuse the use of MS Paint, we have here the angle difference $d/r-\cos^{-1}(r/(r+h_0))$ as the green angle. The red bar shows where the hidden observer is, but $H_h$ is the lateral distance along the horizontal radius extended out to the bar. The bottom triangle shows how $H_h$ is deduced - that triangle is what you get if you rotate the horizontal with $H_h$ on it by the blue angle, so that it can be compared past Earth's curvature, and then the green angle is what you get, and hopefully there's enough geometric intuition here to carry the rest of it through. I admit my explanation was hard to read, sorry.

[image: Diagram]

Answer (score 0):

This is a really old post and I don't think you still need or want the answer to this question (maybe you reached it yourself?), but recently I had the same problem and went out to find the answer, so to anyone who might land on this same post and may be looking for the answer, here it is. (btw, sorry if I am using not convenient notation for this site, I just created an account to answer this specific question)

The only part I couldn't derive is the apparent radius of the Earth considering refraction, but it can be found in wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_refraction#Terrestrial_refraction) and there is a citation to this paper https://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu//full/2006Obs...126...82Y/0000091.000.html, maybe the derivation is in there, I am not sure.

So, assuming the effective radius of Earth to be $R'=\frac{R}{1-k}$, where k is the refraction coefficient of the atmosphere:

[here is the image that I made so you can see the math](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DY8dS.png)

$\overline{AO} = h_0+R' \\  \text{by trigonometry, }\angle AOT=arccos(\frac{R'}{h_0+R'}) \text{ and } \angle AOB=\frac{d}{R'}\\ \angle TOB=\frac{d}{R'}-arccos(\frac{R'}{h_0+R'})\\ \text{by the law of sines } = \frac{R'}{sin(\frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{d}{R'}+arccos(\frac{R'}{h_0+R'}))} = \frac{h_h+R'}{sin(\frac{\pi}{4})}=h_h+R'\\ \text{since sin((pi/4)-x) = cos(x), } \frac{R'}{cos((\frac{d}{R'})-arccos(\frac{R'}{h_0+R'}))}=h_h+R' \\ \text{and, finally, by simple algebra, } h_h= \frac{R'}{cos(\frac{d}{R'}- arccos(\frac{R'}{h_0+R'}))}-R'$

anyways, worth mentioning I am using radians instead of degrees, just because it makes it easier to associate the distance along the curvature to the radius, and all the pi got cancelled out, so they don't mess up with the formula anyways.